# MonngoDB :Filter multiple elements within array of objects from multiple parameters

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have documents in the format as:

```
"email": "eight@gmail.com",
    "primary_skills": [
        {
            "name": "Angular",
            "rating": 4.5
        },
        {
            "name": "React",
            "rating": 3.0
        }
    ],
    "secondary_skills": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "rating": 4.5
        },
        {
            "name": "SQL",
            "rating": 3.0
        },
        {
            "name": "Vue",
            "rating": 3.0
        }
    ]
```

How do I filter the users based on:

1.) Users who have Angular and React (or any other multiple skills) as primary skills with a rating of greater than or equal to 3(same rating applicable for react and angular)

2.) Users who have Angular and Python (doesn't matter if it is in the primary or secondary, but both should be present in either primary or secondary) as their skills with a rating greater than or equal to 4?

And also for both first and second part, it should for a dynamic length of filters. for example, one can search for ['angular', 'react'] but others could search for ['angular', 'react', 'python', 'aws'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first filter you can use `$all` and you will get all values that contains an specific array like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "primary_skills.name": {
    "$all": [
      "Angular",
      "React"
    ]
  }
})
```

This query will return the documents that contains "Angular" and "React" into `primary_skills.name`. Is neccessary the document contains all values indicated in the array.

Also, for your second filter, you can use `$and` and `$or`.

```js
"$and": [ 
 { "$or": [ { "primary_skills.name": "Angular" }, { "secondary_skills.name": "Angular" } ] },
 { "$or": [ { "primary_skills.name": "Python" }, { "secondary_skills.name": "Python" } ] }
]
```

In this case, `$and` is to ensure both conditions are true. These two conditions are two `$or`.
`$or` ensure that exists the word as `primary_skills` or `secondary_skills`.

And, to add the rating , is necessary use `$elemMatch` to compare the same object into the array. And again `$in` to compare with an array.
Using `$elemMatch` is to ensure there is an object with matches the two fields in this way:

```js
"primary_skills": {
  "$elemMatch": {
  "name": {
    "$in": [
      "Python",
      "AWS"
    ]
  },
  "rating": {
    "$gte": 3
  }
}
}
```

Now, all together...

```js
db.collection.find({
  "primary_skills.name": { "$all": [ "Angular", "React" ] },
  "$or": [{
      "primary_skills": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
          "name": { "$in": [ "Python", "AWS" ] }, 
          "rating": { "$gte": 3 } } } 
  }, {
      "secondary_skills": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
          "name": { "$in": [ "Python", "AWS" ] }, 
          "rating": { "$gte": 3 } } }
    }]
})
```

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MFnX-6DiwpV)

Comment: But what about the rating part? I have tried what you suggested, it works correctly with names but filtering with correct rating doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read. I'm going to edit to add this part.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: For both the first and second part, it should work for a dynamic length of filters. for example, one can search for ['angular', 'react'] but others could search for ['angular', 'react', 'python', 'aws'].

Comment: Check the last update. Is using `$in` as in the frist part of `find`.

Comment: @RohitNawale if I were you i'd buy this guy a coffee  :-)